# Replicate QGIS operations in PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis

What is the best practice for calling QGIS/SAGA/GRASS algorithms from pure Python e.g. the command prompt or in PyCharm? I know that from QGIS -> Processing -> History, I can retrieve the code and parameters of algorithms run from the GUI, but I am unsure which previous steps (e.g. import modules and Python configurations) I have to set up to run those commands successfully.

Comment: Have you read [GRASS and Python](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on a Windows machine and your goal is, to have GIS related functions without having to start/use QGIS, you may want to try installing GDAL from binaries on your machine. This way you can access a lot of geo related functions with python, without having to use Qgis directly.

To install it you need the binaries and pythong bindings from GISInternals. Also make sure to set up your enviroment and user variables correctly.

if everything is right, you may now use :

```
 import gdal
```

and everything attached to it.
I know GDAL is not everything QGIS has to offer but it is a solid start.